# Periodo ipotetico

Tags: grammar

Secondo la grammatica il periodo ipotetico consiste nei seguenti tipi:

1. realtà: se+indicativo (protasi) + indicativo presente/futuro semplice/imperativo (apodosi);
2. possibilità: se + congiuntivo imperfetto (protasi) + condizionale semplice (apodosi);
3. irrealtà: a) uguale al punto 2; b) se + congiuntivo trapassato (protasi) + condizionale composto (apodosi).

Ma a volte trovo qualche frase che non rispetta questa regola, e sembra che sia ugualmente ammissibile, faccio due esempi:

Frase 1: Se il testo originale **è** corretto, nemmeno il peggiore traduttore automatico **commetterebbe** questo errore.
In questa frase c'è la combinazione "se+indicativo (protasi) + condizionale (apodosi) 
Frase 2: Se non **fosse** per la distanza notevole, l'**avrei** già **fatto** molto prima. 
In questa frase c'è la combinazione "se+congiuntivo imperfetto (protasi) + condizionale composto(apodosi)
Per favore mi potete dire se queste frasi sono accettabili? Se sono sbagliate, gentilmente potete farmi la correzione? Grazie.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152123/discussion-on-question-by-wensi-periodo-ipotetico); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.